# English input to kannada script conversion(No translation) In android

Tags: android, unicode

I have been to many sites which provides the facility for converting the English input to kannada script. But i need to integrate this feature in android app
is there any way to script conversion.
please help me

Ex:In English keyboard: Kannada

output:ಕನ್ನಡ

I tried by changing locale but it is only working for predefined strings

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.

Comment: Is there any way to convert please help